# Increment a Google Sheet cell by 1 via App Scripts

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to increment a number in a Google sheet cell by one, when I custom menu item is clicked. But the result in the spreadsheet is either #NUM! or 1range. I've tried a number of different methods, as shown in the comments in my code.

Note that the number is stored as a custom number format so that it has 4 leading zeros, eg: 00001

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('OrderNumber')
      .addItem('Generate next order number', 'menuItem1')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

     var range = sheet.getRange("N11");

     range = 1 + +range;
     // For the previous line, I've also tried: range = 1 + parseInt(range) 
     // For the previous line, I've also tried: range = 1 + Number(range) 

     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N11').setValue(range);
}
```

As a test if it just set it to a number it shows in the spreadsheet correctly, e.g:

```
range = 5
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('N11').setValue(range);
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) is an object containing a lot of information: values but also formatting, data validation, font size etc.

You need to call `getValue()` on `range` first to extract the number:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("N11").getValue();
```